# Almost identical queries but large time difference in execution

Tags: mysql, performance, explain, query-performance

**Exhibit A**

`SELECT SUM(value) FROM Credits RIGHT JOIN calendar ON datefield = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)) WHERE confirm = 1 && reason = 1 && country = 'it' && created_at >= 1408060800 && created_at <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)) ORDER BY created_at ASC;`

**Exhibit B**

`SELECT SUM(value) FROM Products RIGHT JOIN calendar ON datefield = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)) WHERE confirm = 1 && reason = 2 && country = 'it' && created_at >= 1408060800 && created_at <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)) ORDER BY created_at ASC;`

No difference between table structure or indexes (except for few [2] more columns on `Products`). Also there are no indexes on these columns.

`EXPLAIN` shows a set of **2010** records on `calendar`, **336460** on `Credits` and **376680** on `Products`.

And - basically - when running the first query, it returns data in 0.9x seconds, when running the second it returns data in "unknown" time (I need to kill it).

How is this fixable?

**EDIT**

I'm running MySQL (Percona) with InnoDB.

`calendar` is a dumb table with days on it (it's a workaround in order to return time-based statistical data with no date gaps - [read more](http://www.media-division.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/))

**EDIT 2**

`CREATE TABLE` statement for `Credits`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Credits` (
`id_transaction` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`id_f` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`id_aC` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`reason` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`value` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`payment` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`country` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`curr` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cod_op` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`confirm` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`email` varchar(200) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`id_if` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fee` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
PRIMARY KEY (`id_transaction`),
KEY `id_user_idx` (`user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=441611 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
```

`CREATE TABLE` statement for `Products`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Products` (
`id_transaction` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`id_f` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`id_aC` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`reason` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`off` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`value` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`payment` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`country` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`curr` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cod_op` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`confirm` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`email` varchar(200) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`id_if` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fee` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_transaction`),
 KEY `id_user_idx` (`user`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=426453 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
```

`CREATE TABLE` statement for `calendar`:

```
CREATE TABLE calendar (datefield DATE)
```

`calendar` is then filled by

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_calendar(start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
BEGIN
  DECLARE crt_date DATE;
  SET crt_date=start_date;
  WHILE crt_date < end_date DO
    INSERT INTO calendar VALUES(crt_date);
    SET crt_date = ADDDATE(crt_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
 END WHILE;
END |
DELIMITER ;

CALL fill_calendar('2010-01-01', '2014-12-31');
```

`EXPLAIN` for `Credits`:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | calendar  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   2010 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Credits   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 325337 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

`EXPLAIN` for `Products`:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | calendar  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   2010 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Products  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 362422 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

**EDIT 3**

@Mihai requested some statistics about the `reason` column in both `Products` and `Credits`.

```
SELECT COUNT(id_transaction), reason FROM Credits GROUP BY reason;
+-----------------------+--------+
| COUNT(id_transaction) | reason |
+-----------------------+--------+
|                109805 |      1 |
|                 83141 |      4 |
|                 26883 |      6 |
|                 87811 |      8 |
|                  3067 |      9 |
|                  2050 |     10 |
|                 25491 |     11 |
|                    99 |     14 |
+-----------------------+--------+

SELECT COUNT(id_transaction), reason FROM Products GROUP BY reason;
+-----------------------+--------+
| COUNT(id_transaction) | reason |
+-----------------------+--------+
|                350443 |      2 |
|                 10052 |      3 |
|                   618 |     12 |
+-----------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64615/discussion-on-question-by-xcore-almost-identical-queries-but-large-time-differen).